# Looking for reseller community site software, as turnkey as possible (like boardgamegeek.com sales area)

Tags: web-development, ecommerce

I'm looking for a product oriented resale site like Boardgamegeek.com's used board game section, or G2a.com that is product oriented (rather than seller oriented like Etsy).  And is as turnkey as possible (Wordpress plugin, Magento Commerce add-on, etc). Open source, or proprietary software sold with source is acceptable as well.  The language the code is written in is not a huge concern.

Key features:

- Seller registration and item listing tools.
- Search by product -> then list sellers offering that product.
- Seller reviews/rating system
- Cart and checkout preferred, but if necessary, I can bridge it to a
  shopping cart

Answer (score 1):

**[Sharetribe](https://www.sharetribe.com/)** ([source code](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe))

The most well-known open source solution for marketplaces. Built on Ruby, has a strong community. Perfectly adapted for MVPs and proof-of-concept projects. Can handle sales and services/rentals.

**Their own description:**

Sharetribe is an open source platform to create your own peer-to-peer marketplace.

---

**[Cocorico](https://www.cocolabs.io)** ([source code](https://github.com/Cocolabs-SAS/cocorico))

Specially designed for service & rental platforms, possibly the most powerful solution in that field. Large community for a new project (3rd largest?). Built on PHP (Symfony). Perfectly adapted to service & rental marketplaces (AirBNB, BlaBlaCar, Drivy…).

---

**[Sellacious](https://www.sellacious.com)**

Sellacious is also open source and it's based on Joomla.

**Their own description:**

Offer unlimited variants of the products in your store and let that be managed by a mile with sellacious, with an admin panel so strong and easy, you can now manage your products with least of your efforts involved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently looking at Spree-Suppliers on Github, but am looking for more options as well.

https://github.com/johndavid400/spree_suppliers